# HTML5 Canvas draws on tablets & phones, but not on desktop?

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, desktop

I'm unable to post the code as per company guidelines (my apologies).

I have a canvas that is purposed for taking a customer signature, and the image saved. Now it was working previously without issue (3-4 days ago); but today I was doing some testing and noticed it won't draw/sign while on desktop. So I freaked out and tested on my phone, and tablet (both Android) and it works just fine. Same as on an iPad, it works; but return to PC, and it doesn't go. I stepped through the dev tools, and it shows the functions are being hit, and coordinates are being recorded, yet nothing shows on screen.

Just looking for potential causes as after about 4 hours of searching, and trying different things to no avail; I'm still at square one.

Comment: Without code, we will have very little chance to help.

Comment: Resolved, window zoom broke things somehow. Reset zoom to default and everything works.